# Laravel From::button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-form

How can I populate dynamic value for `{{Form::button() }}`?

**This is what I have got:**

```
{{ Form::button('Button Text', array('class' => 'btn btn-block btn-success','type'=>'submit')) }}
```

**HTML Output is:**

```
 <button class="btn btn-block btn-success" type="submit">Button Text </button>
```

How can I display `$user` as a button text? (.i.e $user is a dynamic value here)

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter is the text value. You just need to pass the dynamic value as first parameter, like this:

```
{{ Form::button($username, array('class' => 'btn btn-block btn-success','type'=>'submit')) }}
```